# How to convert string data into datetime in SQL Server using dateadd() function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This "1432443679" is my string which is stored in a column called `Due_date`. I need to convert this to a datetime using `dateadd` function by the below formula.

When I applied this in Excel workbook I get datetime as "5/24/2015 5:01:19". But in SQL Server I couldn't get the time and date part.

- Formula: `1970/01/01 12:00:00 Am + (1432443679/86400)`
- Excel worksheet result is `5/24/2015 5:01:19`

Please assist me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select dateadd(SS,1432443679,CAST('1970-01-01' as datetime))
```

No need to convert seconds to number of days by dividing by 86400.
In DateAdd() function use seconds as datepart to directly add seconds to 1970-01-01 and get the date.

```
select dateadd(ss,cast(Due_Date as bigint),cast('1970-01-01' as datetime))
from tableName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mhasan

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DateTimeAsString as varchar(30) = '1432443679';

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(@DateTimeAsString as bigint), '1970-01-01T00:00:00');
```

Result:

```
24.05.2015 05:01:19
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zohar Peled